# android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground" meaning

Tags: android

I was going through from an example of `RecyclerView` but while looking I have found this line written in my Parent View

```
android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
```

Guys what does it mean I tried looking in values/attr but not getting much idea.

Answer (score 0):

please search in style sheet

@android:drawable/ background